# How to test tooltip text with mocha, webdriver-io and phantomjs?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver-io to test input forms and would like to test the appearance of a tooltip text upon tab out if the input text does not meet a specified criteria. Below is what a tried without success

```js
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var browser = webdriverio.remote({desiredCapabilities:{browserName: 'phantomjs'} });
...
describe('Test tooltip text', function(){

  before(function(){
    //return browser.url(site);
  });

  before(function(){
    // return browser.setValue(key, value);
  });

  it('should display a tooltip text', function(){
    broswer.getHTML('body').then(function(form){
      form.should.contain('message in tooltip')
    });
  });// it block ends

 });// describe block ends
...
```

This test redirects me to the original form without the tooltip. When I try enter values in this input form in a chrome browser, I do see the tooltip. I know that the value entered in test is correct because, I console log the input and after tab out, I see that input field style shows red in HTML. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I found this solution to capture the tooltip text using setTimeout. Here is my test:

```js
... 
it('should display a tooltip text', function(){
   broswer.getHTML('body').then(function(form, done){
     form.should.contain('message in tooltip');
     setTimeout(done, 1000);
  });
});// it block ends
...

...
```

I hope this solution is helpful to others!

Comment: I don't know why there is no syntax highlight for the code part!

Answer (score 2):

You can read "title" tag of the element which is nothing but the tooltip.

Comment: This is a good start. But is there no way to verify the tooltip text itself?